# Connection problem with sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, connection

i tried this code:
http://programming-guides.com/java/tcp-client-server-chat
(full example)

and it's working but when i switch the "host" int the client side to an external IP (insted of localhost) it give me this error:
"Cannot get IO for connection to.."

i treid to switch the port but it didnt work..

Comment: This might sound stupid but do you actually have a deployed chat server at the external ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Is the server running on that remote machine? Is the port open in the firewall?

Comment: yes, the server running on this remote machine, and yes the port is open in the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Try to [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to the remote host. If you get an connection the example maybe wrong. If not, you cannot connect to that host: host not exists, not listen on that port, port is filtered, etc, etc.